# Rails imports stylesheet files twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have a Rails app with the following application.scss.erb file:

```
<% puts "in application.scss.erb" %>
@import "main";
```

That's all it does.  It just imports a separate `app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss.erb` file.

Inside the main.scss.erb file, I have this content

```
<% puts "in main.scss.erb" %>
```

When I start the rails server in development mode, then visit the home page, I see this output in the console

```
in application.scss.erb
in main.scss.erb
in main.scss.erb
```

Why does main appear twice?

Answer (score 3):

Does your application.scss have anything extra in it like :

```
*= require_tree .
```

by any chance?

Another thing you can check is to look at your network tab in the browser dev tools and actually see if it is loading / requesting it twice or if something else might be going on.